# Docker COPY command not mounting a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
Host OS: Linux
Container OS: Linux
```

I'm trying to learn how to use docker. I use docker-compose and I'm successfully building images and running containers.

Now if I want to mount some directory inside the container the documentation says that I should use the COPY command inside Dockerfile.

```
COPY /path/to/my/addons/ /path/to/directory/inside/container
```

Sadly when I compose this container the COPY command is ignored and my stuff from /path/to/my/addons doesn't make it to the container.

I've also tried with ADD command, but same problem.

Comment: Are you rebuilding the image after adding this line? Or are you just running `docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Absolute paths

First, you can't use absolute paths for `COPY`. All paths must be [inside the context of the build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), which means relative to the `Dockerfile`. If the folder structure on your host is like this

```
my-docker-directory
-- Dockerfile
-- docker-compose.yml
-- addons
```

then you're able to use `COPY addons /path/to/directory/inside/container`. For all subsequent explanations, I assume that you have an `addons` folder relative to the `Dockerfile`.

## *Mounting* a directory

`COPY` doesn't simply mount a folder to the *container* at runtime. It doesn't really *mount* the directory at all. Instead, `addons` is *copied* to `/path/to/directory/inside/container` inside the *image*. It's important to understand, that this process happens unidirectional (host > image) and only happens when the image is build.

`COPY` is designed to add dependencies to the image that were required during buildtime like source code that got compiled to binaries. That's the reason why you can't absolute paths. A `Dockerfile` usually is placed together with source code/config files at the top level area.

The build process of an image happens only on the first run, except you force it using `docker-compose up --build`. But it doesn't seem that this is what you want. To mount a directory from the host at runtime, use a `volume` in the `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./addons/:/path/to/directory/inside/container
```

## When to use `COPY` and when volumes?

It's important to realize that `COPY` and `ADD` will *copy* the stuff into the image at buildtime, where `volumes` mount them from the host at runtume (without including them in the image). So you usually copy general things to the image, that the users needs like default configuration files.

Volumes are required to include files from the host like customized configuration files. Or persistent things as the data-directory of a database. Without volumes those containers work, but are not persistent. So all content would get lost when the container restarts.

Please note that one doesn't exclude the other. It's fine to `COPY` a default configuration for some application in the image, where the user may override this with volumes to modify them. Especially during development this can make things easier because you don't have to rebuild the entire image for a single changed config file*

* Altough it's a good practice to optimize Dockerfiles for the integrated caching mechanism. If a `Dockerfile` is well written, rebuilding small config changes often doesn't take too long. But that's another topic out of this scope.

## More detailled explanation with example

### Basic setup with `COPY`  in `Dockerfile`

As simple example, we create a `Dockerfile` from the nginx webserver image and copy html in it

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY my-html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Lets create the folder with demo content

```
mkdir my-html
echo "Dockerfile content" > my-html/index.html
```

and add a minimalistic `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
```

If we run it for the first time using `docker-compose up -d`, the image got build and our test page is served:

```
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# docker-compose up -d
Creating network "docker-so-example_default" with the default driver
Creating docker-so-example_test_1 ... done

root@server2:~/docker-so-example# curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker-so-example_test_1)
Dockerfile content
```

Let's manipulate our testfile:

```
echo "NEW Modified content" > my-html/index.html
```

If we request our server with `curl` again, we get the old response:

```
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker-so-example_test_1)
Dockerfile content
```

To apply our content, a rebuild is required:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build
```

Now we can see our changes:

```
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker-so-example_test_1)
NEW Modified content
```

### Use volumes in `docker-compose`

To show the difference, we use volumes by modifing our `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./my-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Now restart the containers using `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` and try it again:

```
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# echo "Again changed content" > my-html/index.html
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker-so-example_test_1)
NEW Modified content
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# echo "Some content" > my-html/index.html
root@server2:~/docker-so-example# curl $(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' docker-so-example_test_1)
Some content
```

Notice that we didn't re-build the image and our modifications apply immediately. Using volumes, the files are not included in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Take your addon folder to location where your Dockerfile is and then run

```
mkdir -p /path/to/directory/inside/container
COPY ./addons/* /path/to/directory/inside/container
```

Comment: Tried. No luck :(

Comment: Try COPY ~/path /path

Comment: You cannot use absolute host paths in a Dockerfile `COPY` or `ADD` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

COPY command inside a docker file copies the content to the image while building. mounting a volume is a different thing. for mounting you need to use

```
docker run -v <volume_name>:<volume_name> ...
```

what exactly you want to achieve ? Do you want to see the folders inside containers in your host ?

Comment: No I want to edit files on the host and have that directory 'mounted' somewhere inside the container.

Comment: -v should do it. try

Comment: I'm not using "docker run", so there's no place for me to use -v option :(

Comment: The question stated mounting it should have stated that I am unable to copy from my host to the container :)

Comment: yeah I see that now.. but it was my first day of learning and I dind't pay attention to the details.. :)